# Android SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range problem

Tags: android, sqlite

In android I am using the following statement.

```
model = dataHelper.rawQuery("SELECT _id, engword, lower(engword) as letter FROM word WHERE letter >= 'a' AND letter < '{' AND engword LIKE '%" + filterText + "%'", new String[ {"_id","engword", "lower(engword) as letter"});
```

It is throwing `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x132330`

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The right statement is :

```
model = dataHelper.rawQuery("
    SELECT _id, engword, lower(engword) as letter
    FROM word W
    HERE letter >= 'a'
    AND letter < '{'
    AND engword LIKE ? ORDER BY engword ASC
    ",
    new String[] {"%" + filterText + "%"}
);
```

Answer (score 23):

You provided 3 parameters but you have no `?` in your query. Pass null instead of string array as the 2nd argument to the `rawQuery` or replace `_id`, `engword` and `lower(engword) as letter` in your select string by `?`

1)

```
model = dataHelper.rawQuery("SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM word WHERE letter >= 'a' AND letter < '{' AND engword LIKE '%" + filterText + "%'",new String[] {"_id","engword", "lower(engword) as letter"});
```

2)

```
model = dataHelper.rawQuery("SELECT _id, engword, lower(engword) as letter FROM word WHERE letter >= 'a' AND letter < '{' AND engword LIKE '%" + filterText + "%'", null);
```

**Edit:**
As @Ewoks pointed out, the option (1) is incorrect, since prepared statements can get parameters (?s) only in WHERE clause.

Comment: what should be the statement : model = dataHelper.rawQuery("SELECT ?, ? FROM word WHERE lower(engword) >= 'a' AND lower(engword) < '{' AND engword LIKE '%" + filterText + "%'",null);

Comment: ur welcome.. I spent good part of today trying to make parameters and rawQuery work.. This was not my issue but it will help somebody ;) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is like me trying (and failing) to get this working with `getContentResolver().query` here how I managed it:

***Updated thanks to comments from @CL and @Wolfram Rittmeyer, as they said this is the same as for rawQuery ***

Correct way:

```
  public static String SELECTION_LIKE_EMP_NAME = Columns.EMPLOYEE_NAME
            + " like ?";            

  Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION_LIKE_EMP_NAME, new String[] { "%" + query + "%" }, null);
```

Previous answer that was open to SQL injection attack:

```
public static String SELECTION_LIKE_EMP_NAME = Columns.EMPLOYEE_NAME
            + " like '%?%'";

String selection = SELECTION_LIKE_EMP_NAME.replace("?", query);

Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
```

Comment: This is wrong, and will introduce formatting problems and allow [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/). You are supposed to put the `sensorId` into `selectionArgs`.

Comment: hmm, ok good point Re:SQLInjection, but so would the other answers (not a defence, just saying). When you say 'wrong' I'm not clear what you mean? it does work. I'd love to use `selectionArgs` that just doesn't work.

Comment: The first answer (the answer marked as "answer" by the owner of this question) doesn't have the SQL injection problem because it's using `selectionArgs`. Android takes care to transform those to safe Strings.