# Android SQLite query with 'WHERE' selection arguments not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this code:

```
if (idListe.size()>0)
        {
        strIdArray = new String[idListe.size()];
        idListe.toArray(strIdArray);
//my query starts here
        c = dbHelper.query(true, DataBaseHelper.DB_COURSE,
                dbHelper.COURSE_TABLE_AUFGABEN, new String[] {
                dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_ID,
                dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_ADRESSID,
                dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_KURSART }, dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_ID + " = ?",strIdArray,
                dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_KURSART, null,
                dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_KURSART + " ASC", null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        }
```

And get a this error:

> 01-15 13:01:27.489: E/AndroidRuntime(703): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x3fd490

I've tried several combinations and the result always stays the same. If the size of the strIdArray is '1' the query works. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the size of the strIdArray is '1' the query works. What am I doing
>   wrong here?

You're only having one ? while you provide several parameters when the size of strIdArray is bigger than one.

Comment: That makes sense. But how can I write multiple ?s in the code?
I would have to make a very large string:
for (String t : strIdArray)...
dbHelper.COURSE_AUFGABEN_COLUMN_ID + " = ?"

And then finally set the String t as my where clause. Is that correct? That would be a very strange approach...

Comment: Your answer is correct. I've used my approach and made one large String and it works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code fragment does not explain too much, since it uses some (German) 3rd party library and it hides the actual query.

However you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716543/android-sqliteexception-bind-or-column-index-out-of-range-problem) if is relevant.

It would be easier to help if you could provide more details about the actual query.

Comment: I've edited the code. I hope it clarifies the code. I've been to the link you've posted, but it doesn't help me, since I'm not using a rawquery